# Find similarities and differences between two large files based on the first column

Tags: perl, hash

I have two tab-delimited files with over a million lines, and I need find based on first column how many values are common and how many are specific to just one of the files.

I am trying to do it in Perl with following code, but it isn't working right.

I need to consider the computational time given the size of the files.

Can someone please help me to correct this, or suggest a more efficient method?

#### left.txt

```
K00134:78_1 272 1   3057610
K00134:78_0 272 1   3057610
K00134:78_2 272 1   3057610
K00134:78_3 272 1   3057610
```

#### right.txt

```
K00134:78_1 272 1   3057610
K00134:78_5 272 1   3057610
K00134:78_6 272 1   3057610
K00134:78_3 272 1   3057610
```

#### Perl code

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %Set;

open (SET1, "<", "left.txt") or die "cannot open file";

while (<SET1>) {
    my @line = split (/\t/, $_);
    $Set{$line[0]} = $line[1];
}

my @k = keys %Set;
foreach my $key (@k) {
    print "$key, $Set{$key}\n";
}
close SET1;

open (SET2, "<", "right.txt") or die "cannot open file";
print "common:\n";

while (<SET2>) {
    chomp;

    if ( exists $Set{"$_"} ) {
        print "$Set{$_}\n";
    }
}

close SET2;
```

The output should look like this, listing the common fields based on first column  -

```
common lines - 
K00134:78_1 272 1   3057610
K00134:78_3 272 1   3057610
```

uncommon lines -  left.txt

```
K00134:78_0 272 1   3057610
K00134:78_2 272 1   3057610
```

uncommon lines -  right.txt

```
K00134:78_5 272 1   3057610
K00134:78_6 272 1   3057610
```

Also, I am trying to add mismatches from each file as output too, but I am not sure if its possible given size of the files. Thanks!

Comment: Where are tabs in the input? What problems do you have with your script?

Comment: the text files are tab delimited files. it des not print out the common lines at the end

Comment: Why don't you `split` the lines read from SET2?

Comment: How many distinct values do you expect in the first column? Why are you printing the entire hash after reading `left.txt`? Have you considered using a database?

Comment: You should take a look at [*How do I compute the difference of two arrays? How do I compute the intersection of two arrays?*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays%3f-How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays%3f) from `perldoc perlfaq4`

Comment: showing expected output would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second read loop code is wrong. It should split by tabs and check. Change it to:

```
while (<SET2>) {
    my @line = split (/\t/, $_);
    print $_ if exists $Set{$line[0]};
}
```

And it will work. Your approach is OK-ish. Since you only want to compare the first column, you don't have to set the value of the $Set{} to the second column ($line[1]) you can just set it to '' in attempt to save memory. Also, to save memory make sure left.txt is the smallest of the two. Here is a working example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %Set;

open (SET1, "<", "left.txt") or die "cannot open file";

while (<SET1>) {
    my @line = split (/\t/, $_);
    $Set{$line[0]} = '';
}

close SET1;

open (SET2, "<", "right.txt") or die "cannot open file";
print "common:\n";

while (<SET2>) {
    my @line = split (/\t/, $_);
    print $_ if exists $Set{$line[0]};
}

close SET2;
```

EDIT - here is another approach that will give you what you want

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %Set;

sub readFile {
    my ($fn, $bit) = @_;
    open (F, "<" ,$fn) or die "can't open file";
    while (<F>) {
        my ($k) = split (/\t/, $_);
        $Set{$k} = $Set{$k} || [0, $_];
        $Set{$k}[0] |= $bit;
    }
    close F;
}

sub showByBit {
    my ($k, $bit) = @_;
    foreach my $key (@{$k}) {
        my $a = $Set{$key};
        print $a->[1] if $a->[0] == $bit;
    }
}

readFile('left.txt', 1);
readFile('right.txt', 2);
my @k = keys %Set;

print "common lines -\n";
showByBit(\@k, 3);

print "uncommon lines - left.txt\n";
showByBit(\@k, 1);

print "uncommon lines - right.txt\n";
showByBit(\@k, 2);
```

Comment: Ahaha! `OK-ish`: you can really say that?

Comment: Thanks a lot @niry, is there anyway to output the mismatch lines as well? I am trying to do a count of mismatches as well

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - yes you can say that... freedom of speech?

Comment: @AnkP - I edited my answer to include different approach that will give you what you need.

Comment: @niry: I didn't know it exits, I believed you invented it. But since I found it in the urban dictionary.

Comment: Hi @niry thanks for your edited answer which prints out all the common and unique lists. Is there a way to juts count the unique and common lines rather than printing? As When I add count++ to count lines in showByBit I am not getting right number. Thanks!

Comment: @AnkP, add `my $count=0;` at the top of showByBit, replace `print $a->[1]` with `++$count` and add `print $count, "\n";` after the foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot @niry I will try this!